# How to match regex only for part of the url and the rest of the url

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I have 2 links

1. https://www.example.com/routes/a/b/x
2. https://www.example.com/routes/a/b

i have a regex to match the first link and not the second -

`routes\/.*\/.*\/`

What is the regex to capture the second **but** not the first?

a,b and x could be any string

Comment: Try `routes/[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+$`

Comment: its still doesn't work,

Answer (score 2):

```
routes\/[^\/]+\/[^\/]+$
```

- `[^\/]+` Not a `/` one or more times
- `\/` literal `/`
- `$` End of string

Answer (score 0):

The pattern `routes\/.*\/.*$` only matches the second link below (don't enable multiline flag):

https://www.example.com/routes/a/b/x

https://www.example.com/routes/a/b

Comment: i'm asking how to match only for the second link and not the first

Comment: @Chehmer I see. I have revised my answer.

Comment: apologise, but this still capture also the first link

Comment: Do you have the MULTILINE enabled? $ symbol does not work with multiline flag.

Comment: i'm using it for google analytics so i'm not sure how to control it